# re.sub() negative look behind + negative look ahead

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

Remove every occurence of `'` from a string except when a word ends with s,
if word ends with `s'` or `'s` it the `'` is left in. EVERY other occurrence is removed.

Example:

```
Andrea's -Stays as is
Kids' - stays as is
'Kids' --> Kids
Ki'd's' --> Kids'
```

WHat I came up with so far :

```
\'(?!s )
```

this matches the first example and ignores it.

[here is it working](https://regex101.com/r/wY8kG1/4)

I have a problem with the rest

Comment: Your last example doesn't match your description. The second apostrophe is before `s`, and the last one is after `s`, so they shouldn't be removed.

Comment: Before an `'s`? Do you mean before an `s`?

Comment: @Barmar updated example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'([^'\s]+)'
```

You can try this.Replace by `\1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/2#python